# String to YYYY-MM-DD date format in Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

So I've looked through documentation and previous answers on here, but can't seem to figure this out.

I have a `STRING` that represents a date. A normal output looks as such:

`2018-09-19 17:47:12`

If I do this, I get it to return in this format `2018-09-19 17:47:12.000`:

```
SELECT
date_parse(click_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') click_time
FROM
table.abc
```

But that's not the output I need. I was just trying to show that I'm close, but clearly missing something. When I change `click_time` to `date_parse(click_time,'%Y-%m-%d')`, it sends back `INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: Invalid format: "2018-09-19 17:47:12" is malformed at " 17:47:12"`

So there's clearly something I'm not doing correctly to get it to simply return `2018-09-19`.

Comment: I can't find documentation for all of this, but logically you want to parse to a datetime or timestamp or whatever, specifying the *existing* format, and then perform a second conversion from the datetime/timestamp back to a string with the *desired* format. So the first part is already working - I'd expect to see a `date_format` function or something similar

Answer (score 2):

`date_parse` converts a string to a timestamp. As per the documentation, `date_parse` does this:

```
date_parse(string, format) → timestamp
```

It parses a string to a timestamp using the supplied format.

So for your use case, you need to do the following:

```
cast(date_parse(click_time,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) as date )
```

For your further reference, you can go to the below link for prestodb online documentation  https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html